# Linear transformation change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by $T(x,y,z)=(5x+3y-3z,-y,6x+3y-4z)$.

$1$. Let $w_1=(2,0,1)$ and $w_2=Tw_1$. Show that $W=span\{w_1,w_2\}$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$2$. Show that $T(W)=W$.

$3$. Find some vector $v$ such that $w_1,w_2,v$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$4$. Find the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the basis $w_1,w_2,v$.

For part $1$, $T=\begin{bmatrix}5&3&-3\\0&-1&0\\6&3&-4\end{bmatrix}$, so $w_2=Tw_1=\begin{bmatrix}5&3&-3\\0&-1&0\\6&3&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\0\\8\end{bmatrix}$, so $W=span(\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7\\0\\8\end{bmatrix})=span(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix})$. Therefore, $W$ is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For part $2$, I didn't really get it. What does $T(W)$ mean?

For part $3$, by adding a vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$,we will form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For part $4$, should I use the change of basis method for linear transformation? I had a hard on doing this. Can someone help me to check I had done and show me what to do for part $2$ and part $4$? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 2, $T(W)=\{Tw\;|\;w\in W\}$.

For part 4, yes, use the change of basis formula. Remember that the columns of a change-of-basis matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: So for part 4, I use $T(w_1),T(w_2),T(v)$ as the matrix representation of $T$ and I got $\begin{bmatrix}7&11&3\\0&0&-1\\8&10&3\end{bmatrix}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. Do you remember the change-of-basis formula for the matrix of a linear transformation? It involves two matrix multiplications.

Comment: Oh, so I let $B=\begin{bmatrix}2&7&0\\0&0&1\\1&8&0\end{bmatrix}$, then the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the new basis is $BTB^{-1}$. Is it correct this time?

Comment: Almost there. Your matrix $B$ maps from the new basis to the standard one.

Comment: Should I use $B^{-1} T B$ instead?

Comment: That’s right. You map from the new basis to the standard one, apply $T$, then map from the standard basis back to the new one.